# Using FileReader() but result isn't in form body when POSTed

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express, handlebars.js

As the title says, I am trying to upload an image to a form, Base64 encode the image and then submit the form to a server.

Here is my view/form

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title">Add Product</h1>
<form class="form" action="/add-product" method="POST">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Title" name="title"/>
  <input name="Image" type='file' onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL(this)" accept="image/*" />
  <textarea type="text" placeholder="Start Typing Here..." name="body"></textarea>
  <input type="text" placeholder="SKU" name="SKU"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" name="Price"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Weight" name="Weight"/>
  <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is my frontend js

```
function encodeImageFileAsURL(element) {

  var file = element.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function() {
    console.log('RESULT', reader.result)
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Finally, the code on my server

```
router.post('/add-product', function(req, res, next) {
  axios.post('https://' + API + '@insta-ecom.myshopify.com/admin/products.json/',{
      product: {
        title: req.body.title,
        body_html: req.body.body,
        images: [
          {
            attachment: req.body.image
          }
        ],
        sku: req.body.sku,
        price: req.body.price,
        weight: req.body.weight,
        tags: 'test'
      }
  })
```

Everything returns with a value except for `req.body.image`

Comment: Just to clarify, `console.log('RESULT', reader.result)` does return a result

Comment: AFAICT, `reader.result` is set a value on any form element. So the form is submitted to your server still in `req.files`.

Comment: req.files and req.file both return undefined.